# ¿Como puedo hacer para que cada vez que aprete un boton me salga un array diferente?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este codigo, no se como hacer para que, cada vez que se haga un cambio se muestre en el html cuando se pulsa el boton.

Cada vez que se pulse el boton tiene que aparecer una linea en la cual se vea como se ordena la serie númerica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<body>
    <br>
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Ordenar</button>
    <br>
     <h2>RESULTADO:</h2>
       <h3 id="alg"></h3>
    </body>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
     function num(arr) { 
      var leng = arr.length,
          i, x, min;
                
         for(i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
             min=i;
             for(x = i + 1; x < leng; x++) {            
                 if (arr[min] > arr[x]) {              
                     min = x;
                 }            
             }
             a(arr, i, min);
         }
         return arr;
     }
     function a(arr, f, s) {
         console.log(arr);
         var temp = arr[f];
         arr[f] = arr[s];
         arr[s] = temp;    
     }

    document.getElementById("alg").innerHTML = num([8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 7]);
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Quieres que aparezcan todos los pasos realizados con un solo click, o por cada click las valla ordenando de a a una ?

Comment: que por cada click se ordene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si analizas tu código, tienes un algoritmo de ordenación con dos bucles anidados, que en pseudocódigo sería algo como :

```
Para cada posicion...
  Para cada número
     Comprobar si es el menor y guardar su posición si lo es
  fin Para
  colocar el menor en la posición actual
fin Para
```

Lo que quieres es que cada vez que pulsas un botón se ejecute una iteración del bucle más externo, con lo que tu función `num` podría quedar así:

```
function num(arr, i) { //i es la posición a rellenar con el menor número restante
  var leng = arr.length, x, min;
  min=i;
  for(x = i + 1; x < leng; x++) {            
    if (arr[min] > arr[x]) {              
      min = x;
    }
  }
  a(arr, i, min);
  return arr;
}
```

Es decir, quitamos el bucle más externo y el índice i pasa a ser un parámetro

Ya sólo nos falta poder llamar a la función repetidas veces, para lo que necesitamos que el array se mantenga entre llamadas (ahora mismo se genera un array cada vez que llamas a num) y podrás verlo en funcionamiento:

```js
let indice = 0;
let array = [8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 7];
function myFunction() {
  function num(arr,i) { 
    var leng = arr.length,
      x, min;
      min=i;
      for(x = i + 1; x < leng; x++) {            
          if (arr[min] > arr[x]) {              
              min = x;
          }            
      }
      a(arr, i, min);

      return arr;
  }
  function a(arr, f, s) {
      document.getElementById("alg").innerHTML += arr + '<br>';
      var temp = arr[f];
      arr[f] = arr[s];
      arr[s] = temp;    
  }

    num(array,indice);
    if (indice < array.length - 1) {
      indice ++;
    }
}
```

```html
<br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Ordenar</button>
<br>
<h2>RESULTADO:</h2>
<h3 id="alg"></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya casi lo tienes, solo tienes que concatenar en cada iteracion en lugar de desplegar en consola asi:

```html
<body>
    <br>
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Ordenar</button>
    <br>
     <h2>RESULTADO:</h2>
       <h3 id="alg"></h3>
    </body>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
     function num(arr) { 
      var leng = arr.length,
          i, x, min;
                
         for(i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
             min=i;
             for(x = i + 1; x < leng; x++) {            
                 if (arr[min] > arr[x]) {              
                     min = x;
                 }            
             }
             a(arr, i, min);
         }
         return arr;
     }
     function a(arr, f, s) {
         document.getElementById("alg").innerHTML += arr + '<br>';
         var temp = arr[f];
         arr[f] = arr[s];
         arr[s] = temp;    
     }

        num([8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 7]);
    }

    </script>
```